# Menu not always using correct link

Tags: menus, navigation

I moved a Wordpress install from /wordpress/ folder to root by just copying the index and .htaccess file to root and then updating the permalinks etc.

All works fine but I have a problem with the menu in the top nav.

The menu works fine while you're on the main page and scrolls down to the area it should be. But when you go to one of the posts under services like http://angrychickenmedia.com.au/filming/ and then press on for instance "team" in the menu it will point to http://angrychickenmedia.com.au/wordpress/#team thus suddenly adding the /wordpress/ to it and ending up at a blank page.

Anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that all of the links inside that menu are custom menu links, based on the classes "menu-item-type-custom" & "menu-item-object-custom".

You should be able to go into the menu and put whatever you want in the url field.

If you are using hash links (#team) and may have to put the full url
`http://angrychickenmedia.com.au/#services` as opposed to `#services`

You can also double check the Settings > General > Blog/Site URL to ensure that the /wordpress sub directory is not listed there.

Though it doesn't seem that those will actually link anywhere because there is no div with that ID on the page. Where are these links supposed to go to?

Answer (score 0):

Update the permalink-structure by setting it to default and back to your preferred setting under `Settings > Permalinks`. It should work correctly after doing this

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Jan but the problem persists.